# Поиск суммы в std::vector с использованием find() и accumulate();

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Есть:

```
//..
std::vector<int> ivec{1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5};
//..
```

Как с помощью двух обобщенных алгоритмов `find()` и `accumulate()` посчитать сумму одинаковых элементов? То есть получить сумму всех 1, затем 2 и т.д.
PS Вопрос упрощён, на деле используется вектор своих объектов. Интересует сама идея реализации поиска суммы при помощи `find()` и `accumulate()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, если уж так хочется помучиться, и **обязательно** `find/accumulate`, то

```
int valueSumFind(vector<int>::const_iterator b, vector<int>::const_iterator e, int val)
{
    auto it = find(b,e,val);
    if (it == e) return 0;
    return accumulate(it,next(it),valueSumFind(next(it),e,val));
}

cout << valueSumFind(ivec.begin(),ivec.end(),5) << endl;
```

Вариант без `find`:

```
int valueSum(const vector<int>& v, int val)
{
    return accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0,
                      [val](int sum, int x){ return (x==val)? sum+x : sum; });
}

 cout << valueSum(ivec,3) << endl;
```

Если вектор отсортирован, а мучиться хочется меньше - то

```
int valueSum(const vector<int>& v, int val)
{
    return accumulate(lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),val),
                      upper_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),val),0);
}

cout << valueSum(ivec,1) << endl;
```

Если еще меньше и одним махом нужно получить все суммы - то (расписываем как сумму, поскольку у вас какие-то свои объекты...)

```
map<int,int> m;
for(auto i: ivec) m[i]+=i;
for(auto i: m)
{
    cout << "Sum for " << i.first << " = " << i.second << endl;
}
```

Comment: Решение с мапом пришло в голову в первую очередь, но настолько элегантной записи я не ожидал :)

Comment: Не совсем, то что надо, но рядом. Мне надо без параметра "int val". благодарю за ответ.

Comment: То есть в функцию просто надо передавать отсортированный вектор объектов, а получать сумму однотипных(одинаковых) объектов.

Comment: Вам нужны ВСЕ суммы? Тогда работайте с `map`. Если не передавать `val` - с чем же тогда должен работать `find`?

Comment: Вот я так же подумал, поломал голову и решил спросить.